# Microsoft Speech Synthesizer PhonemeReached Event generates unrecognized characters for phonemes

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, microsoft-speech-platform

I am using the Microsoft speech SDK and attempting to get the list of phonemes from a string of text as it is speaking. When I inspect the PhonemeReachedEventArgs.Phoneme it displays something that makes me think it its using a different character set.
For instance, the text:

> "this is a sample sentence with Microsoft Speech"

will create a string of phonemes that looks like:

> ↑)'%∟↕'♂ %☼▼'§!)☼!'.←¶ ►▲&☼'

Any suggestions on what I need to do to get a readable string of phonemes?

Comment: Yes, that's what they look like when you use a console mode app.  The characters are actually phoneme table indices, the mapping table [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I saw the table. Not sure that the values map...

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the result as an int:

```
    private static void Synth_PhonemeReached(object sender, PhonemeReachedEventArgs e)
    {
        int sym = (int)e.Phoneme[0];
    }
```

Why it's passed as a string in the first place is beyond me, and I could not find any mention of this *anywhere* on the web.

Once you have the symbol, you can look it up in the [American English Phoneme Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that Hans Passant linked to above.